# How to put equation within listing caption?

Tags: math-mode, listings

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Here is an equation $y=2x$.]
def y(x):
  return 2*x
\end{lstlisting}
```

But I get an error due to the equation in the caption. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try to put the caption inside brackets, `caption={...}`

Comment: Worked, thanks!